# Prolog - Recursive with facts

Tags: prolog

Firstly, I want to mention that this question was asked in a previous exam but I don't quite understand the answer. I just need someone to shed some light.

The code is decribed as follow :

```
state( 1, f, 2 ).
state( 2, o, 3 ).
state( 2, l, 4 ).
state( 3, n, 5 ).
state( 3, r, 6 ).
state( 4, o, 7 ).
state( 5, d, 8 ).
state( 6, t, 9 ).
state( 6, m, 10 ).
state( 7, u, 11 ).
state( 8, u, 12 ).
state( 10, e, 13 ).

find_( Y1, [ L | ES ], X ) :-
    state( Y1, L, Y2 ),
    find_( Y2, ES, X ).
find_( Y, [], Y ).
```

Let's say we call `find_(1, Z, 9)` the answer will be `Z = [f,o,r,t]`.

Before the recursive call, is it going to unify with all possible value for `Y2` ? If so, why the answer is not including the l from the second unification for `state( 2, l, 4)`.

I've tried the trace mode, but that didn't help me much.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you draw the state facts as a graph of nodes and edges you get.

[image]

Now the query ask for a path from 1 to 9 and the result is a list of the edges from 1 to 9. They are colored green. The edges are f,o,r,t.

Sometimes trying to understand the problem as Prolog is harder than trying to understand the problem in a different manner. As I often note when stuck one option that often helps is to get out a pen and paper.

> Before the recursive call, is it going to unify with all possible
>   value for Y2 ?

No. Prolog unifies the predicates/facts in the order they are written and then backtracks to the next one upon failure. So `state(2,o,3)` is tried first and succeeds for which the answer is printed. Then because there is a choice point for `state(2,_,_)` for which `state(2,l,4)` is then selected. However this eventually fails and thus is not included as a separate answer.

TL;DR

I built the graph using [graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/) [dot](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/pdf/dotguide.pdf) with the file

so_question_07.gv

```
digraph so_question_07 {


    node_01 [label="1", color="green", fontcolor="green"];
    node_02 [label="2", color="green", fontcolor="green"];
    node_03 [label="3", color="green", fontcolor="green"];
    node_04 [label="4"];
    node_05 [label="5"];
    node_06 [label="6", color="green", fontcolor="green"];
    node_07 [label="7"];
    node_08 [label="8"];
    node_09 [label="9", color="green", fontcolor="green"];
    node_10 [label="10"];
    node_11 [label="11"];
    node_12 [label="12"];
    node_13 [label="13"];

    color=black;

    node_01 -> node_02 [label="f",shape=oval, color="green", fontcolor="green"];
    node_02 -> node_03 [label="o",shape=oval, color="green", fontcolor="green"];
    node_02 -> node_04 [label="l",shape=oval];
    node_03 -> node_05 [label="n",shape=oval];
    node_03 -> node_06 [label="r",shape=oval, color="green", fontcolor="green"];
    node_04 -> node_07 [label="o",shape=oval];
    node_05 -> node_08 [label="d",shape=oval];
    node_06 -> node_09 [label="t",shape=oval, color="green", fontcolor="green"];
    node_06 -> node_10 [label="m",shape=oval];
    node_07 -> node_11 [label="u",shape=oval];
    node_08 -> node_12 [label="u",shape=oval];
    node_10 -> node_13 [label="e",shape=oval];
}
```

Here is a simple batch file to covert the gv file to an svg

```
SET PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin";PATH=%PATH%

dot -Tsvg so_question_07.gv -o so_question_07.svg
```

Comment: So well explained !! If I could give you a thousand upvote I would! :)

Comment: @Vini I wasn't sure if switching from Prolog to explain it would help. Glad it worked for you.