# ; (or) operator in Prolog not returning true unless the left side is true, even if the right side of the operator returns true by itself

Tags: prolog, or-operator

I'm trying to return `true` if either of the two rules on opposite sides of an `or` operator succeed in Prolog. It only works if what's on the left side of the `or` operator is found to be `true`.

It seems like my code should work according to http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/dictionaries/prolog/or.html.

`Case2` works when `case1` is commented out, so it should be returning `true`, but because it is on the right side of the operator, it isn't. (?)

For clarity, the parameters mean `Person1`, `Person2`, `TypeOfCousinsTheyAre`, `DegreesRemovedTheyAre`. I am trying to write rules that determine whether two people are first-cousins-once-removed.

Here is the line that uses the `or` operator which won't return `true` if the right side is true:

```erlang
cousins(A, B, 1, 1) :- ( cousinsCase1(A, B, 1, 1) ; cousinsCase2(A, B, 1, 1) ).
```

Other things I have tried:

(1) Omitting the `or` operator and writing two identical functions, but whenever they are called and the top one fails, my program crashes.

```erlang
cousins(A, B, 1, 1) :- var(FirstCousin),
                       cousin(A, FirstCousin, 1, 0),
                       parent(FirstCousin, B),
                       A \= B.

cousins(A, B, 1, 1) :-  var(P1),
                        parent(P1, A),
                        cousin(P1, B, 1, 0),
                        A \= B,
                        A \= P1,
                        B \= P1.
```

(2) I have also tried an `if`-statement to call the other function if the first one fails, but it crashes if the first case fails again.

```erlang
cousins(A, B, 1, 1) :- cousinsCase1(A, B, 1, 1) -> true ; cousinsCase2(A, B, 1, 1)).
```

Is there a different way to call the other rule if the first one fails?

***EDIT***

To take the advice given, here is more of the code:

Facts:

```erlang
parent(gggm, ggm). 
parent(ggm, gm).
parent(gm, m).
parent(m, self).
parent(self, d).
parent(d, gd).
parent(gggm, gga).
parent(gga, c12a).
parent(c12a, c21a).
parent(c21a, c3).
parent(ggm, ga)
parent(ga, c11a).
parent(c11a, c2).
parent(gm, a).
parent(a, c1).
parent(m, s).
parent(s, n). 
parent(n, gn).
parent(c1, c11b).
parent(c11b, c12b).
parent(c2, c21b).
parent(c21b, c22).
parent(c3, c31).
parent(c31, c32).
```

Other rules I have written in order to get the above ones to work:

```erlang
% Sibling Rule
sibling(A, B) :- parent(P, A), parent(P, B), A \= B.
% First-cousin Rule:
cousin(A, B, 1, 0) :- sibling(P1, P2), parent(P1, A), parent(P2, B).
% Second-cousin Rule:
cousin(A, B, 2, 0) :- parent(P1, A),
                      parent(P2, B),
                      parent(PP1, P1), % your grandparent
                      parent(PP2, P2), % your grand-aunt/uncle
                      sibling(PP1, PP2). % they're siblings
% 3rd-cousin and more Rule
cousin(A, B, M, 0) :- ReducedM = M - 1,
                      cousin(A, B, ReducedM, 0).
```

Calls to the above rules: Sidenote: Both calls do work but the problem is getting them both to work without commenting out the other rule:

**cousins(self, c11b, 1, 1).**

This call corresponds to the first "1st-cousin, once-removed" case and the case returns the correct answer of true if the other case is commented out.

**cousins(self, c11a, 1, 1).**

This call corresponds to the second "1st-cousin, once-removed" case and the case returns the correct answer of true if the other case is commented out.

Comment: the problem is clearly somewhere else in your code.  [mcve] could clarify things here... focus on one error at a time, too.

Comment: In your two clauses for the `cousins/2` predicate, the goals `var(FirstCousin)` and `var(P1)` are **always** true as they are the first goals in the clause body and the arguments are not variables in the clause head.

Comment: I am considering answering this, but the problem is that I have to create so much of the work from scratch because you don't include it, that I am not helping you learn, but just giving you the answer. I don't even know what the numbers in your predicates mean, and where are the facts that represent the relationships of the people?

Comment: Another thing that would help you with your problem is using test cases. My current belief is that one or both of your cousins/4 predicates is wrong. If you have test cases and test each one separately then you will know if it is those predicates that are throwing off the logic. Just because you learned to use ;/2 does not mean that you are using it wrong and is what you should be focusing attention. But as I noted you left so much out in your question I can only guess.

Comment: Of interest: [Cousin tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin#/media/File:CousinTree.svg)

Comment: One thing that really helps when working on these relationship problems is to see a visual representation of the graph or tree and one tool widely used and easy to use once you get the hang of it is [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/). Here is an example I used on with another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49909525/1243762) and it includes the GraphViz file. Also GraphViz has a StackOverflow tag [GraphViz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphviz) so you can also get help with it here.

Comment: In Prolog `=` is unification not assignment, so `ReducedM = M - 1` is wrong. To evaluate a mathematical expression and bind the result to a value in Prolog use [is/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=is/2), e.g. `ReducedM is M - 1`

Comment: You changed the name of the predicate `cousins/2` to `cousin/2` along the way and need to update the question so the predicate names are the same. Please double check your work as every mistake and thing you do not do for those helping you just waste our time. I typically will give about 5-10 minutes to working on an answer and if that time is taking fixing typos etc. then then the time is used and I move on without an answer being given.

Answer (score 4):

This is a comment in an answer because it will not format correctly in a comment.

What most beginners to Prolog don't realize early enough is that Prolog is based on logic (that they realize) and the three basics operators of logic `and`, `or` and `not` are operators in Prolog, namely (`, ; \+`). It is not realizing those operators for what they really are.

---

Starting with `not` which in Prolog use to be [not/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=not/1) but is now commonly [(\+)/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%5C%2B/1).

```
?- \+ false.
true.

?- \+ true.
false.
```

or using the older `not/1` which you can use but is like speaking in a Shakespearean play because it is no longer done this way. I am including this here because many older examples still have it in the examples this way.

```
?- not(true).
false.

?- not(false).
true.
```

---

Next is `and` which in Prolog is [,/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%27,%27)/2).

The reason many new Prolog users don't see this as `logical and` is that a `,` in many other programming languages is seen as a statement separator ([Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(syntax)#Statements)) and acting much like a `,` in an English sentence. The entire problem with understating `,` in programming is that it is really an operator and is used for so many things that programmers don't even realize that it should almost always be thought of as an operator but with many different meanings, (operator overloading). Also because `,` is used as a statement separator, the statements are typically put on separate lines and some programmers even think that a comma (`,`) is just a statement end like a period (`.`) is a line end in a sentence; that is not the way to think of these single character operators. They are operators and need to be seen and comprehended as such.

So now that you know where and how your ideas that cause you problems are coming from, the next time you see a comma `,` or a period `.` in a programming language really take time to think about what it means.

```
?- true,true.
true.

?- true,false.
false.

?- false,true.
false.

?- false,false.
false.
```

---

Finally logical or which in Prolog is [;/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3B)/2) or in DCGs will appear as [|/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%27%7C%27)/2). The use of `|/2` in DCGs is the same as `|` in [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form).

```
?- true;true.
true ;
true.

?- true;false.
true ;
false.

?- false;true.
true.

?- false;false.
false.
```

The interesting thing to note about the results of using or (`;`) in Prolog is that it will they will return when true as many times as one of the propositions is true and false only when all of the propositions are false. (Not sure if proposition is the correct word to use here). e.g.

```
?- false;false;false.
false.

?- false;false;true.
true.

?- true;false;true.
true ;
true.

?- true;true;true.
true ;
true ;
true.
```

---

In case you didn't heed my warning about thinking about the operators when you see them, how many of you looked at

```
?- true,true.
true.
```

and did not think that would commonly be written in source code as

```
true,
true.
```

with the `,` looking like a statement end. `,` is not a statement end, it is the `logical and` operator. So do yourself a favor and be very critical of even a single `,` as it has a specific meaning in programming.

A reverse way to get this idea across is to use the addition operator (`+`) like a statement end operator which it is not but to someone new to math could be mistakenly taken to be that as seen in this reformatting of a simple math expression.

```
A =
1 +
2 +
3
```

That is not how one is use to seeing a simple math expression, but in the same way how some programmers are looking at the use of the `,` operator.

Over the years one thing I have seen that divides programmers who easily get this from the programmers who struggle with this all their careers are those that do well in a [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) class easily get this because they have to parse the syntax down to the tokens such as `,`, then convert that into the [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics) of the language.

For more details see section **1.2. Control** on page 23 of this [paper](https://www.info.ucl.ac.be/~pvr/Thesis/ThesisMain.pdf).

---

**EDIT**

You really need to use test cases. Here are two to get you started.

This is done using SWI-Prolog

```
:- begin_tests(family_relationship).

sibling_test_case_generator(ggm ,gga ).
sibling_test_case_generator(gga ,ggm ).
sibling_test_case_generator(gm  ,ga  ).
sibling_test_case_generator(ga  ,gm  ).
sibling_test_case_generator(m   ,a   ).
sibling_test_case_generator(a   ,m   ).
sibling_test_case_generator(self,s   ).
sibling_test_case_generator(s   ,self).

test(01,[forall(sibling_test_case_generator(Person,Sibling))]) :-
    sibling(Person,Sibling).

cousin_1_0_test_case_generator(gm  ,c12a).
cousin_1_0_test_case_generator(ga  ,c12a).
cousin_1_0_test_case_generator(m   ,c11a).
cousin_1_0_test_case_generator(a   ,c11a).
cousin_1_0_test_case_generator(self,c1  ).
cousin_1_0_test_case_generator(s   ,c1  ).
cousin_1_0_test_case_generator(d   ,n   ).
cousin_1_0_test_case_generator(c12a,gm  ).
cousin_1_0_test_case_generator(c12a,ga  ).
cousin_1_0_test_case_generator(c11a,m   ).
cousin_1_0_test_case_generator(c11a,a   ).
cousin_1_0_test_case_generator(c1  ,self).
cousin_1_0_test_case_generator(c1  ,s   ).
cousin_1_0_test_case_generator(n   ,d   ).

test(02,[nondet,forall(cousin_1_0_test_case_generator(Person,Cousin))]) :-
    cousin(Person, Cousin, 1, 0).

:- end_tests(family_relationship).
```

**EDIT**

[image]

By !Original:[J Di](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:J_Di)Vector: Matt Leidholm ([LinkTiger](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:LinkTiger)) - Own work based on: [Cousin tree.png](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cousin_tree.png), Public Domain, [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=1976404)

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer.

Using this code based on what you gave in the question and a few changes as noted below this code works. Since you did not give test cases I am not sure if the answers are what you expect or need.

```
parent(gggm, ggm).
parent(ggm, gm).
parent(gm, m).
parent(m, self).
parent(self, d).
parent(d, gd).
parent(gggm, gga).
parent(gga, c12a).
parent(c12a, c21a).
parent(c21a, c3).
parent(ggm, ga).
parent(ga, c11a).
parent(c11a, c2).
parent(gm, a).
parent(a, c1).
parent(m, s).
parent(s, n).
parent(n, gn).
parent(c1, c11b).
parent(c11b, c12b).
parent(c2, c21b).
parent(c21b, c22).
parent(c3, c31).
parent(c31, c32).

% Sibling Rule
sibling(A, B) :-
    parent(P, A),
    parent(P, B),
    A \= B.

% First-cousin Rule:
cousin(A, B, 1, 0) :-
    sibling(P1, P2),
    parent(P1, A),
    parent(P2, B).

% Second-cousin Rule:
cousin(A, B, 2, 0) :-
    parent(P1, A),
    parent(P2, B),
    parent(PP1, P1), % your grandparent
    parent(PP2, P2), % your grand-aunt/uncle
    sibling(PP1, PP2). % they're siblings

% 3rd-cousin and more Rule
cousin(A, B, M, 0) :-
    % ReducedM = M - 1,
    ReducedM is M - 1,
    ReducedM > 0,
    cousin(A, B, ReducedM, 0).

cousinsCase1(A, B, 1, 1) :-
    % var(FirstCousin),
    cousin(A, FirstCousin, 1, 0),
    parent(FirstCousin, B),
    A \= B.

cousinsCase2(A, B, 1, 1) :-
    % var(P1),
    parent(P1, A),
    cousin(P1, B, 1, 0),
    A \= B,
    A \= P1,
    B \= P1.

cousins(A, B, 1, 1) :-
    (
        cousinsCase1(A, B, 1, 1)
    ;
        cousinsCase2(A, B, 1, 1)
    ).
```

The first change was as Paulo noted and the checks for var/2 were commented out.

The next change was to change `=` to `is`.

The third change to stop infinite looping was to add `ReducedM > 0,`.

This query now runs.

```
?- cousins(Person,Cousin,1,1).
Person = gm,
Cousin = c21a ;
Person = ga,
Cousin = c21a ;
Person = m,
Cousin = c2 ;
Person = a,
Cousin = c2 ;
Person = self,
Cousin = c11b ;
Person = s,
Cousin = c11b ;
Person = d,
Cousin = gn ;
Person = c12a,
Cousin = m ;
Person = c12a,
Cousin = a ;
Person = c12a,
Cousin = c11a ;
Person = c11a,
Cousin = self ;
Person = c11a,
Cousin = s ;
Person = c11a,
Cousin = c1 ;
Person = c1,
Cousin = d ;
Person = c1,
Cousin = n ;
Person = n,
Cousin = gd ;
Person = m,
Cousin = c12a ;
Person = self,
Cousin = c11a ;
Person = d,
Cousin = c1 ;
Person = gd,
Cousin = n ;
Person = c21a,
Cousin = gm ;
Person = c21a,
Cousin = ga ;
Person = c11a,
Cousin = c12a ;
Person = c2,
Cousin = m ;
Person = c2,
Cousin = a ;
Person = a,
Cousin = c12a ;
Person = c1,
Cousin = c11a ;
Person = s,
Cousin = c11a ;
Person = n,
Cousin = c1 ;
Person = gn,
Cousin = d ;
Person = c11b,
Cousin = self ;
Person = c11b,
Cousin = s ;
false.
```